# Problema para conformar la clase para leer usuarios en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, class

Parece que de alguna manera no logra acceder a la clase constructora de usuarios.

Este es el error que devuelve:

> Undefined variable: Usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 26
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\index.php(104): RepositorioUsuario::obtener_todos(Object(PDO)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog03\app\RepositorioUsuario.inc.php on line 26

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
class RepositorioUsuario {

public static function obtener_todos($conexion) {
    $usuarios = array();

    if (isset($conexion)) {

        try {
            include_once 'Usuario.inc.php';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";

            $sentencia = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $sentencia->execute();
            $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll();


            if (count($resultado)) {
                foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
                    $usuarios[] = new $Usuario(
                    $fila['id'], $fila['nombre'], $fila['email'], $fila['password'], $fila['fecha_registro'], $fila['activo']
                    );
                }
            } else {
                print "No hay usuarios";
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            print "ERROR: " . $ex->getMessage() . '<br>';
        }
    }
    return $usuarios;
}

}
```

Comment: No entendi tu respuesta, saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte

Comment: Estas instanciando mal a tu class `Usuario` has puesto `new $Usuario()` , te sobra `$`, cámbialo por `new Usuario(....)`

Answer (score 0):

En tu código estás intentando inicializar una clase desde `$Usuario`, pero no tienes dicha variable declarada en tu código.

```
$usuarios[] = new $Usuario(
                    $fila['id'], $fila['nombre'], $fila['email'], $fila['password'], 
                    $fila['fecha_registro'], $fila['activo']);
```

Esto puede llevarnos a dos cosas...

1. Tu clase se llama `Usuario` y solo te haz equivocado al tipear, por ende debes eliminar el `$` antes del nombre.
2. Estás trabajando clases de forma dinámica (Llamándolas desde un string) y te haz olvidado de declarar la variable `$Usuario` con el nombre de una clase valida.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue un error que no pude detectar, puse $ donde no iba. Muchas gracias por sus aportes, son una comunidad excelente.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, procura seleccionarla como mejor respuesta para ayudar a más personas en el futuro. éxito!